# axios.post in not giving any values when i try with basic login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to do a Basic Login with "axios" post function but here is my code and response Help me out , new in app development

```
let {data} = await axios({
     method: 'post',
     url:'http://alpha.fc.emisha.co/index.php?option=com_api&app=fglogin&resource=fglogin&format=json',
     auth:{
               username:'test@test.com',
               password:'password'
         }   
     })   

console.log(data);
```

After executing the above code, The following response is received:

```
Object {
  "api": "",
  "data": Object {},
  "err_code": 403,
  "err_msg": "Empty password not allowed.",
  "response_id": "",
  "version": "",
}
```

Comment: It appears as though the data is not properly formatted for the api. How does the api doc say the request should be formatted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at the API documentation

You can try wrapping you auth object inside data

```
 let {
     data
 } = await axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: 'http://alpha.fc.emisha.co/index.php?
     option = com_api & app = fglogin & resource = fglogin & format = json ',
     data: {
         auth: {
             username: 'test@test.com',
             password: 'password'
         }
     }
 })
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: Alternatively he could also try removing the auth object and passing the username and password directly. Impossible to know without the api docs.

Comment: yeah agree with you, It is very important to read the docs and understand it before calling any end-point

Comment: Will ask the person to make the doc , thanks for your help guys learning my stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Problem not in axios side.
You have answer  "err_msg": "Empty password not allowed."
Take a look at manual to your API

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the resurrecting a stale thread. However, sending username & password for each API request is deprecated. You should create a API token from the administrator, and use that for authentication. The token needs to be sent in the `Authorization` header as a Bearer token.